# What is POSTGIS_VERSION 2.1.7+dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1?

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, postgis

I can understand 2.1.7 but what is +dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1 coming after that ?

I am now build postgis docker container from appropriate/docker-postgis

and am getting error

```
E: Version '2.1.7+dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1' for 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1' was not found
E: Version '2.1.7+dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1' for 'postgis' was not found
```

seems to be a problem of package management?

How could I find fix this? How could I find all "subversions" +dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1.

thx

Comment: It's a valid version of a debian package. File an issue to the docker image repository.

Comment: That 2.1.7 not in apt postgresql repo (maybe removed). You can check available package names at http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes using only version number 2.1.7 is not enough, as there are different OS, architectures (or even git branches as you can see), so developers append these specifics to the version to avoid confusion. If you used:

```
apt-get update postgresq-2.1.7
```

It would not make sense (or it would and would give you default option), because for this product version-number is not good enough for Docker to set up your environment.

```
dfsg = Debian Free Software Guidelines (specifies it is for specific version of Debian system, not for redHat for example)
git - version/branch specified
pgdg80 = PostgreSQL packages and backports for Debian/Ubuntu
```

Take a look [here](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.debian/month=20150601)